# ISO-8859-1 character encoding not working in Linux

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have tried below code in windows and able decode the message .But same code when i have tried Linux it's not working.

```
String message ="Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶";
String encodedMsg = new String(message.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(encodedMsg);
```

I have verified and could see the default character set in Linux platform  is UTF-8(Charset.defaultCharset().name())

Kindly suggest me how to do same encoding Linux platform.

Comment: I am not Linux user but for those who are and may try to help you consider clarifying what you mean by "it's not working". What did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: Actually when i am running this code in window machine, I am able to encode this message as "ööööö" but the same encoding not occurred in Linux platform

Comment: "but the same encoding not occurred in Linux platform" from your example I don't see any place where you are actually using `encodedMsg` (like printing it). Could you edit it to add something along `System.out.println(encodedMsg);` *and include **actual** result which you are getting on Linux*?

Answer (score 3):

The explanation for this, is, almost always, that somewhere bytes are turned to characters or characters are turned to bytes there where the encoding is not clearly specified, thus, defaulting to 'platform default', thus, causing different results depending on which platform you run it on.

Except, every place where you turn bytes to chars or chars to bytes in your snippet of code explicitly specified encoding.

Or does it?

> `String message ="Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶";`

Ah, no, you forgot one place: **javac itself**.
You compile this code. That'll be where raw bytes (because the compiler is looking at `ManmohansSourceFile.java`, which is a file, which isn't characters, but a bunch of bytes) - which are converted into characters (because the java compiler works on characters), and this is done using some encoding. If you don't use the `-encoding` switch when running `javac` (or maven or gradle is running `javac`, and it passes an encoding, which one depends on your pom/gradle file), then this is read in using system encoding, and thus whether the string actually contains those bytes - who knows.

This is most likely the source of your problem.

The fix? Pick one:

1. Don't put non-ascii in your source files. Note that you can write the unicode symbol "Latin Capital Letter A with Tilde" as `\u00C3` in your source file instead of as `Ã`. Then use `\u00B6` for ¶.

```
String message ="\u00C3\u00B6\u00C3\u00B6\u00C3\u00B6\u00C3\u00B6\u00C3\u00B6";
String encodedMsg = new String(message.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(encodedMsg);
> ööööö
```

2. Ensure you specify the right `-encoding` switch when compiling. So, if your text editor (that you use to type `String message = "¶";`) is configured as 'UTF-8', and then run `javac -encoding UTF-8 manMohansFile.java`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not sure exactly what you are expecting...your use of the term "encode" is a bit confusing, but from your comments, it appears that with the input "Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶", you expect the output "ööööö".

On both Linux and OS X with Java 1.8, I do get that result.
I do not have a Windows machine to try this on.

As @Pshemo indicated, it is possible that your input, since it's hardcoded in the source code as a string, is being represented as UTF-8, not as ISO-8859-1. Actually, this is what I expected, and I was surprised that the code worked as you expected.

Try creating the input with String.encode(), encoding to ISO-8859-1.